# Resharper ContractAnnotation for null-check method

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a null-check method that can have a different number of arguments:

```
private static bool HasNullArgument(params object[] arguments) => arguments?.Any(item => item == null) ?? true;
```

I know that I can use ContractAnnotation to get rid of the "Possible "NullReferenceException"" warnings for a method that accepts a certain number of arguments, but how can I use it for a method that has a params keyword before the type of the argument?

Comment: use `IEnumerable<object>` instead of params and use ContractAnnotation. Create overload method for one parameter